# hiding div tag when the if condition meets

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to hide a `<div>` tag when my my data is `zero`...

i have `if condition`

```
if ($_SESIION['m1']==0)
{
```

I want the  tag to be de-activated and this is my `<div>` tag

```
<div class="right"><a href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>" class="button" id="checkout"><?php echo $button_checkout; ?></a></div> 

else
```

the `<div>` should be activated..

I really dont know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to completely remove the div, do this;

```
if( !empty( $_SESSION[ 'm1' ] ) )
{
    //echo your div here, it will only appear when m1 is not 0/false/blank/null
}
else
{
    //m1 is 0/false/blank/null, you can print out a relevant message here
}
```

If you want to include the div in the HTML, but hide it, just add the necessary style;

```
<div class="right" <?php if( empty( $_SESSION[ 'm1' ] ) ) { ?>style="display:none;"<?php } ?>>
    <a href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>" class="button" id="checkout"><?php echo $button_checkout; ?></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton.. it worked!. Is it possible to display the message after hiding it? Please suggest

Comment: to display message use "else"

Comment: As Deepanshu said, just add an "else" to the first block. I've added it in my example above for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$hide="";
if ($_SESIION['m1']==0)
{
$hide="style='display:none;'";
}
?>
<div class="right" <?php echo $hide;?>><a href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>" class="button" id="checkout"><?php echo $button_checkout; ?></a></div>
```